# How to print the result of current_date() in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is very simple in python, but I am currently learning PySpark in Databricks.

I just want to see what is returned by `current_date()` in PySpark.

What I have tried:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn

print(fn.current_date())
# Result: Column<'current_date()'>

fn.current_date()
# Result: Out[35]: Column<'current_date()'>

fn.first(fn.current_date())
# Result: Out[36]: Column<'first(current_date())'>

fn.current_date()[0]
# Result: Out[37]: Column<'current_date()[0]'>

display(fn.current_date())
# Result: Column<'current_date()'>
```

Is it just not possible?

Comment: The function that you're trying returns an object of PySpark column type and is used to set a column's values to the current date. You can create a DataFrame with this column and display it to see the results.

Comment: If you just need the current date you can try `datetime.datetime.today()` for the same, since it is python based, it works in PySpark as well.

Comment: @Zero I assumed that column type would be the same kind of object as a pandas series, that I could print or slice. Its very unintuitive. I'll use datetime.datetime.today(), it's just that I'm trying to force myself to use Pyspark more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spark.sql()` for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
print(spark.sql("select string(current_date())").collect()[0][0])
#2023-08-04
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, column expressions (e.g. `current_date()`) do not show results until they are put into dataframes as columns and then the dataframe is instructed to be shown.

Consider the following examples:

---

`spark.range(1)` - creating a dataframe
`.select(F.current_date())` - selecting a column created using function `current_date`
`.show()` - printing the dataframe

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark.range(1).select(F.current_date()).show()
# +--------------+
# |current_date()|
# +--------------+
# |    2023-08-04|
# +--------------+
```

---

`spark.sql("select current_date()")` - creating both dataframe and column using SQL expression
`.show()` - printing the dataframe

```py
spark.sql("select current_date()").show()
# +--------------+
# |current_date()|
# +--------------+
# |    2023-08-04|
# +--------------+
```

---

`.head()` - accessing the dataframe's first row (as a `pyspark.sql.types.Row` object)
`[0]` - accessing the first element ("column") of the row

```py
spark.sql("select current_date()").head()[0]
# datetime.date(2023, 8, 4)
```

---

In Databricks, `display(df)` should also work, but for this you must create the `df`, e.g.:

```py
display(spark.sql("select current_date()"))
```